# Can SVN tell or sort files by the number of times it is revisioned?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am wondering is there a way to find which file is getting affected most frequently in the svn. For e.g., if one file is modified 100 times while other files are modified only some 30-40 times, i want to identify that 100 times modified file.

Is that possible?

Thanks You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library I use for statistics on a SVN repository, while it does not directly answer your question it gives a lot of insight regarding the repository.

The program is called [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/). This is from their overview:

> StatSVN retrieves information from a Subversion repository and generates various tables and charts describing the project development, e.g.
>
> - Timeline for the lines of code
> - Lines of code for each developer
> - Activity by Clock time
> - Authors Activity
> - Author activity per Module
> - Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
> - Stats per directory
> - File count
> - Average file size
> - Largest files
> - ***Files with most revisions***
> - Directory Sizes
> - Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
> - Repository tree with file count and lines of code
> - LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
> - Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days

Comment: It does gave me what i am looking for. It would have been better if it is GUI based. Still, it is a very good choice for free.